# Sharepoint Online REST API: list view threshold exceeded when querying items in subfolder with GetItems

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I need to query items in a given folder and all of its children in a document library with as few APIs as possible.
The ideal solution seemed to be `getItems` with `Scope='RecursiveAll'` and a `FolderServerRelativePath`. However the API below returns an `SPQueryThrottledException` for a specific document library on Sharepoint Online, and I can't figure out the reason.

```
POST <web-url>/_api/Web/Lists(<list-id>)/getItems?$select=*,FileRef

POST BODY:
{
    "query": {
        "odata.type": "SP.CamlQuery",
        "ViewXml": "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>",
        "DatesInUtc": true,
        "FolderServerRelativePath": {
            "DecodedUrl": "<subfolder's-server-relative-path>"
        }
    }
}
```

Some observations:

- The subfolder has 4 files and no folders in it.
- Getting items under any folder in the document library fails with the same error
- The document library has around 6.5k items (folders+files) in it
- `Scope='Recursive'` also fails, but `'Default'` and `'FilesOnly'` work fine
- The same query worked for another document library with 100k files

What's the problem with the query? How can I fix it? If it's impossible to fix, are there any other APIs that can recursively query items in a folder?

Comment: Hi, have you tried changing the view scope to 'Recursive'? [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541467(v%3Doffice.15)) Right now, it instructs SharePoint to return all list items and all list folders from the list which is having 6.5 k items, i.e. exceeding the threshold limit of 5000.

Comment: @UBK 1. Yes, and it also fails. 2. Shouldn't the request only return files & folders in the FolderServerRelativePath? 3. Since I set the RowLimit to 1, I expected the query to shortcut and return a file in the folder, but it didn't work

Comment: Did you solve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "FolderServerRelativePath" with "FolderServerRelativeUrl". The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var viewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
    getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'DL0506',viewXml,'/sites/lz/DL0506/folder1').then(function(data){
         var items = data.d.results;
         for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
             console.log(items[i].FileRef);
         }    
    }).fail(function(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewXml,folderUrl){    
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems?$select=*,FileRef"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml,
                      "FolderServerRelativeUrl": folderUrl 
               }
    };
    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
</script>
```

If you want to get all the files along with associated list items from a specific folder, we can using the REST API below to achieve it.

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<serverrelativefolderurl>')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: 1. Replacing "FolderServerRelativePath" with "FolderServerRelativeUrl" didn't work. 2. I  want to get all list items under a folder and its subfolders, however I don't need their file metadata.

Comment: Did you use /_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<serverrelativefolderurl>')/files?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I'd rather use GetItems with the view-scope set to 'Default' since it gets the items (files & folders) in one API